# PHP cURL in ubuntu server 20.10

Tags: php, curl, ubuntu-server

I have php 8.0.3 running on my server. I've installed curl with the following command:

```
$ sudo apt-get install php-curl
```

Now I can see curl.so in my extensions directory.

In the php.ini I uncommented the line: `";extension=curl"` removing the semicolon. After I restart the apache server I still get this error in the error.log file:

> PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function
> curl_init()

Does anyone knows how to approach this issue?

Comment: Sure you amended the php.ini being used by the PHP used in Apache

Comment: `<?php phpinfo(); ?>` and look for `Loaded Configuration File` to find the one being used

Comment: That was the problem. Had the 8.0 installed but apache was using the 7.4. Solved! Thank you!!